# Clarification and some assistace in my javascript code

Tags: javascript, onload, exif

I have a question and also in need for help with my code.
I'm trying to create a script that can update metadata on picture. user can upload multiple images and the script automatically update the metadata like latitude and longitude from a list.
As i am a newbie in java script i can not understand why when i pass all my coordinates inside reader.onload it only take the last one and assign it to all my pictures.
My idea is: I loop through the images and assign to each image one coordinate chronologically, then i convert the coordinate to exifByte. Till here is all working fine but when i try to attach the exifByte to each image inside reader.onload it takes the last coordinate and assign it to all my images.
I hope the code below is clear enough for you guys 
Any explanation or help would be much appreciated

Thanks

```
<script>

function Initialize() {


    var fileCatcher = document.getElementById('file-catcher');
    var fileInput = document.getElementById('file-input');
    var fileListDisplay = document.getElementById('file-list-display');

  var fileList = [];
  var renderFileList, dispimg;
  var x = [];
  var jpeg;

  fileInput.addEventListener('change', function (evnt) {
    var files = evnt.target.files;
        fileList = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < fileInput.files.length; i++) {
        fileList.push(fileInput.files[i]);
      var file = fileInput.files[i];

      x = (i);
      var gpsIfd = {};
      var rutedata = '<?php echo "$str" ?>';


      points = rutedata.split(";").reverse();
      for (var j=0; j<(points.length-x); j++) {
       var mData = points[j].split(',');}
       console.log("current point:");
       console.log(x)


       var lat = (mData[0]);
       var lng = (mData[1]);

      gpsIfd[piexif.GPSIFD.GPSLatitudeRef] = lat < 0 ? 'S' : 'N';
      gpsIfd[piexif.GPSIFD.GPSLatitude] = piexif.GPSHelper.degToDmsRational(lat);
      gpsIfd[piexif.GPSIFD.GPSLongitudeRef] = lng < 0 ? 'W' : 'E';
      gpsIfd[piexif.GPSIFD.GPSLongitude] = piexif.GPSHelper.degToDmsRational(lng);

      var exifObj = { "GPS":gpsIfd};
      var exifBytes = piexif.dump(exifObj);

      var c = document.createDocumentFragment(); 


      var reader = new FileReader();

      reader.onload = (e) => { // this is the problem loop only the last point'

          var jpeg = piexif.insert(exifBytes, e.target.result);

          console.log(lat); // here is logging the last point only


          var image = new Image();
          image.src = jpeg;
          image.width = 500;
         var el = $("<div></div>").append(image);
         $("#resized").prepend(el);

      };


reader.readAsDataURL(fileInput.files[i]);

    }


    renderFileList();


  });

}


</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since reader is async in nature, you get the last lat-lang. You can use closure to keep data. Else create a function to pass data.

**More:** https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures

```
(function (byte, lats) {
  var reader = new FileReader();

  reader.onload = (e) => {
    var jpeg = piexif.insert(byte, e.target.result);

    console.log(lats); // here is logging the last point only

    var image = new Image();
    image.src = jpeg;
    image.width = 500;
    var el = $("<div></div>").append(image);
    $("#resized").prepend(el);
  };
})(exifBytes, lat);
```

Comment: Hi xdeepakv, many thanks for your answer. my problem is now solved and i'm reading through the documentation you sent so that i can understand . many many thanks